# Probability of n Random Variables Realized As a Volume of a Hypercube

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be $n$-random variables that are all independent and uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,1)$. To compute $P(\Sigma_{j=1}^{n} X_{j} \geq 1)$, we can realize these variables as living on edges of a hypercube of dimension $n$ and use the following formula:

$$P(\Sigma_{j=1}^{n} X_{j} \geq 1) = 1 - P(X_{n} < 1 -\Sigma_{j=1}^{n-1} X_{j})$$

$P(X_{n} < 1 -\Sigma_{j=1}^{n} X_{j})$ can now be realized as as the hyper-volume in a $n$-dimensional hypercube with side-length 1 that lives under the graph of the function $X_{n}=1 -\Sigma_{j=1}^{n} X_{j}$. If am correct in extrapolating from lower-dimensional cases, then this volume will be equivalent to the volume of a hyper-pyramid of height $1$ and base whose hyper volume the volume under the graph of $X_{n-1} = 1-\Sigma_{j=1}^{n-2}X_{j}$ in the $n-1$-dimensional hypercube. I believe the formula for the hyper volume of this hyper-pyramid should be $\frac{1}{n}Bh$ (this agrees in the cases of $n=3$ and $n=2$). Using induction, we can then see that $B=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ and conclude that the desired volume under $X_{n}=1-\Sigma_{j=1}^{n-2}X_{j}$ in the unit hyper-cube of dimension $n$ is $\frac{1}{n!}$. From this we conclude that

$$P(\Sigma_{j=1}^{n} X_{j} \geq 1) = 1 - \frac{1}{n!} = \frac{n!-1}{n!}$$

Is this derivation correct? Please let me know? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Your reasoning is the kind that convinces me at the blackboard, but is not direct enough to make a publishable exposition or lecture notes.

Comment: Thank you; how could it be improved for exposition or lecture notes?

Comment: The more commonly used term instead of pyramid is [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).